# @ViewBuilder on property vs in init, storing closure or result value

Tags: swiftui

What's the difference between:

`@ViewBuilder` on property

```
struct SomeView<Content:View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
}
```

In `init`, storing closure

```
struct SomeView2<Content:View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

In `init`, storing result value

```
struct SomeView3<Content:View>: View {
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
}
```

All solutions seem to work. So why would one select one versus another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone asked in this year's lounge and an Apple engineer recommended storing the the result value.

> Q: But, what’s the recommended way to use a @ViewBuilder for custom
> components: calling it right away in the init() and storing the view,
> or calling it later inside the body and storing the view builder
> itself?
>
> A: We’d generally recommend resolving it right away and
> storing the view

https://onmyway133.com/posts/wwdc-swiftui-lounge/#use-viewbuillder

E.g. this version

```
struct SomeView3<Content:View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
}
```